# JAVA Telegramm bot api. Вывод даты сообщения

Tags: java, telegram-bot, intellij-idea, telegram

Помогите пожалуйста с вопросом. Изучаю java и решил после разного рода упражнений, сделать модное сейчас - телеграмм бота. На данный момент бот умеет отвечать на вопрос "hi" и универсальный ответ на то что он не "знает".

Пример кода ниже. У меня есть два вопроса

1. Есть такое ощущение что код можно сократить и упростить без потери функционала. Но как?
2. Хочу выводить лог в консоль бота для просмотра статистики но даты и не смотря на то что на сервере (Intelj Idea) время стоит правильное и у отправителя тоже, но в консоли вывод такой: "Mon Jan 19 20:42:03 MSK 1970"

> ```
> public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
>         if (update.hasMessage() && update.getMessage().hasText()) {
>                // Берем данные из API Telegram
>             String message = update.getMessage().getText().trim();
>             String chatId = update.getMessage().getChatId().toString();
>             Integer time = update.getMessage().getDate();
>             Date mytime = new Date(time);
>             String user_name = update.getMessage().getFrom().getFirstName();
>             String last_name = update.getMessage().getFrom().getLastName();
>             String nick = update.getMessage().getFrom().getUserName();
>              // Пишем лог в консоль.
>             System.out.println("Пользователь: " + user_name + " " + last_name + " aka " + nick + " написал: "
>                     + message + " " + mytime + " "  );
>
>         SendMessage msg = new SendMessage();
>             msg.setChatId(chatId);
>             msg.setText(cmd.inputmsg(update.getMessage().getText()));
>             try {
>                 execute(msg);
>             } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
>                 e.printStackTrace();
>             }
>         }
>
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### "Упростить"

не меняя сути код можно, убрав лишние переменные.
К примеру, `Integer time` существует только для того, чтобы быть переданной в конструктор `Date()`, от неё вполне можно избавиться:

```java
Date mytime = new Date(update.getMessage().getDate());
```

Вместо заведения кучи переменных под данные пользователя - получите `User user` и в дальнейшем используйте его:

```java
User user = update.getMessage().getFrom();
System.out.println("Пользователь: "+user.getFirstName();
...
```

для SendMessage можно использовать builder.

### Ошибка вывода даты:

в соответствии с документацией [TelegramBot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message) параметр `date` имеет тип `integer` и обозначает *Date the message was sent in [Unix time](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F)*. Обратите внимание, что unix time это количество **секунд**
В то же время конструктор [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) в качестве параметра хочет видеть миллисекунды, т.е. полученное время нужно умножить на 1000:

```java
Date mytime = new Date(update.getMessage().getDate() * 1000);
// возможно, нужно будет привести к long
```